# Change the output of a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a script scheduled to run every night on a Windows environment, that basically serves the purpose of cleaning logs over 30 days old.

When the script does not find logs over 30 days old, it returns an error message:
"ERROR: No Files found with the specified search criteria"

My question is, is it possible to change this message or even to stop the script from returning this message when it doesnt find logs older than 30 days?

Comment: I believe it's possible, but it's hard to know without seeing the code

Comment: Do you have control over the content of the script so you can edit it? Or you control the execution only?

Comment: It's impossible to say, because we don't know how the current  message is being produced. We can't see your screen from where we are - it must be the weather. What a shame you didn't think ahead and include the relevant portions of the code to make sure that telepathy wasn't needed...

Comment: I added the script code.

Comment: If you don't want any log files over 30 days old, you could just use the **/S** option with **ForFiles** and action it against the *.log search mask for the Lev1 section. This may mean only a single command for that level too!

Comment: You lost me there Compo. Can you explain that idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the execution of the script only (and cannot modify the code), you can redirect its ERROR output (STDERR) to `nul` with the following syntax

```
script.bat 2> nul
```

If you want to disable all output (STDOUT and STDERR), use

```
script.bat > nul 2>&1
```

Note that these options are not recommended. You should process the output and act accordingly.

**EDIT:** I see you added the code.
I this case, you need to redirect the output of the `forfiles` command.
You do this in the same way you do it for the script:

```
forfiles ...options... 2> nul
```

or

```
forfiles ...options... > nul 2>&1
```

**EDIT 2:** I'm adding the suggestion of @Squashman's comment:
You could put all the paired FORFILES commands into a code block surrounded by parentheses and then just have one redirect for standard error.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You could put all the paired FORFILES commands into a code block surrounded by parentheses and then just have one redirect for standard error.